# How to split a dictionary into an iterator object in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, iterator

I'm scraping some info from the Yahoo Finance API. I'm currently getting all dividends from a time period for a certain company. I created the following class to model a company:

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self, symbol, dividends):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.dividends = dividends
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.symbol, self.dividends])
```

Dividends is always a dictionary of the following form:

```
{'2016-08-04': '0.57', '2018-05-11': '0.73', '2017-08-10': '0.63', '2018-02-09': '0.63', '2017-05-11': '0.63', '2017-11-10': '0.63', '2017-02-09': '0.57', '2016-11-03': '0.57'}
```

I'd like to create a csv file from this in which each row looks like this:
[image]

But instead I'm getting this from running the script:
[image]

This is the code I use to write into the csv file:

```
def write_into_csv_file(company):
    with open('/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/yahoo_historical.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow(list(company))
```

What can I do to achieve the previously stated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten your dict items into a regular iterator, then use that to build an iterator that includes the symbol

```
from itertools import chain

class Company:
    def __init__(self, symbol, dividends):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.dividends = dividends
    def __iter__(self):
        return chain((self.symbol,), chain.from_iterable(self.dividends.items()))
```

Comment: This is the answer I was going to write.

Comment: @g.d.d.c +1, I've spent too much time thinking about `datetime` sorting (whether OP needs it or not).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries have method `values()` that return its values as an iterator, so you can do `wr.writerow(list(company.dividends.values()))`. However, that very likely will not line up dividends from the same date in the same column in your csv. I recommend using pandas. You can create a dataframe, then fill it with each row being dividends from a company.

```
import pandas as pd
dividends_by_company = 
   pd.DataFrame([company.dividends for company in company_list],
       index = company_list] 
dividends_by_company.to_csv(
    '/Users/rodrigopeniche/Documents/workspace/WebScraping/yahoo_historical.csv')
```